# How create custom plugin in Joomla! for send congratulations on the anniversary?

Tags: php, plugins, joomla

Need send congratulations on the anniversary for my clients.

Any idea how developer this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very bland question but will you you a few pointers.

You will need 2 main things for this.

1. A column in the user database table that stores the anniversary date.
2. A basic PHP script that echo's a congratulations message and the username on the specific date.

Im not going to write the code for you as the database column is easy enough and you can get inspiration for the script from the [Kunena Birthday Module](http://extensions.schultschik.de/mod_sw_kbirthday).

Good luck with it